Is there any penalty for providing half cover to another creature?
This question is more easily illustrated with some elaboration. Let's say a creature, Tank, has very high AC. Tank wants to provide cover for his ally, Squish, against an enemy, Arch. Tank can do this whenever he positions himself between Arch and Squish, and covers at least half of Squish's body.

A target can benefit from cover only when an attack or other effect originates on the opposite side of the cover.


Another creature or an object that covers at least half of the target.

So, whenever Arch's attack against Squish originates from the opposite side of Tank, Squish gains +2 AC. The rationale for the boost in AC presumably is that Squish is harder to hit with Tank "in the way". Ergo, the +2 AC is the result of Arch's projectile hitting Tank, instead.
Are there any mechanics defining how the projectile might hit Tank? Specifically, I'm interested in a situation in which an attack would have hit without the +2 AC. For example:

If Squish has a natural AC of 14 (and gains +2 from Tank for a total of 16) and Arch rolls a 15 to hit, does Tank's AC come into play?

What if the Attack is aimed at Tank instead, and Squish is the one "in the way"? E.g.:

If Tank has a natural AC of 19 (and gains +2 from Squish for a total of 21) and Arch rolls a 20 to hit, would that hit Squish (14 AC) instead?

It seems natural for a DM to impose such a penalty on the creature providing the Half Cover, but I haven't found this described anywhere. Would a rule that imposes such a penalty be completely homebrew, or it is described anywhere? And, importantly, would such a rule cause problems or create imbalance?

This was a Combat Option in the 2014 DMG
As a suggestion, the following Action Option for combat, included in Chapter 9: Dungeon Master's Workshop of the 2014 DMG, could be used:

Hitting Cover
When a ranged attack misses a target that has
cover, you can use this optional rule to determine whether the cover
was struck by the attack.
First, determine whether the attack roll would have hit the protected
target without the cover. If the attack roll falls within a range low
enough to miss the target but high enough to strike the target if
there had been no cover, the object used for cover is struck. If a
creature is providing cover for the missed creature and the attack
roll exceeds the AC of the covering creature, the covering creature is
hit.


+1, nice find on that this used to be an optional rule

@NobodytheHobgoblin I know the question is about the 2024 version of the rules, but theoretically, the new 2024 rules are backward compatible to some degree. At least this rule is still valid under the 2024 rules :D

Ya. I thought it was an optional rule. I don’t have the 2014 DMG, though. I wonder why they it out of the 2024 DMG. It’s  a great option.

@nonymous Same opinion. Some variants or optional rules from the 2014 DMG haven't been included in the new 2024 DMG. Some examples: Facing and Flanking, Speed Factor, Climb onto a Bigger Creature, Disarm, Overrun, Hitting cover, Injuries, or Massive Damage.

It seems like they got rid of many of the options that make the game more complex, more deadly, and more believable. I think they also dropped variant encumberance? I wonder if they used survey statistics or feedback of some sort for that decision or just decided a cotton-padded game for the players is "more fun".

A fun consequence of this rule is that there is no personal cost to providing cover for a party member if your AC is at least two points higher than their AC. So the AC 19 tank pays no cost to cover the AC 15 wizard (if it misses due to cover, with a roll of 15 or 16, it's too low to hit the tank), but if the wizard is provides the cover, they'll take the hit roughly 10% of the time (less if the tank without cover is only hit on a natural 19 or higher). So tanks tank, others probably shouldn't.

There is no such rule, it would be homebrew
You say that Squish enjoys +2 to AC because Tank is in the way, and is therefore possibly being hit by the attack on Squish, but there is no rule in the D&D 2024 rules supporting this.
You can try to justify narratively why the attack does not harm the high-AC Tank, for example, you can say that while the projectile is being blocked by them, it gets deflected by their armor (or fighting style, or whatever), dealing no damage.
The question is natural, and a house-rule (and under the 2014 rules, a combat option in the DMG, thanks to Tarod's answer for pointing that out) I have seen used for it is that you track if you missed the target due to the bonus from half cover, i.e. you would have hit without it, and in that case, you hit the creature giving cover if you overcome its own AC. But this is not rules as written now.
Considering this used to be an official option, its unlikely to be unbalancing. Whether the extra calculation and checking is worth it for verisimilitude, and whether this is more fun, each table has to decide for themselves. For me, it is not worth it, as the players can optimize by putting a Tank up front in front of a Squishy in nearly every fight, whereas many monster groups are all of the same creature, with no large differences in AC, so in practice it will be an assymetrical nerf mostly for the players. And the players generally dislike being nerfed. (Although, if you use this exact rule, and do not just damage the interloper on a near miss, then as soon as they have an AC that is 2 better than the Squish, they never will get hit, and this is less of an issue; thanks to @ShadowRanger for pointing this out.)

It’s a good answer. Upvote. Do you have any sense of the balance of such a rule? Don’t the current rules already allow players to optimize by putting Tank up front? Or, I’m not sure exactly what you mean.

You’re already doing the “extra calculation” whenever you consider half cover, right?

@nonymous As per Tarod's answer, this is not a balance issue. In the 2014 rules this was a rule-supported option. And yes, the caluclation is super simple but you still need to check vs the AC of the other creature (at least following that approach).

Wait, how is this a nerf for the players? A tank protecting a squishy pays no cost (as long as their AC is two points higher, they provide the squishy with extra protection at the cost of positioning alone). For the enemies of uniform AC, the protection is nearly useless; every attack that misses due to cover strikes the one providing cover. The players can get extra defense by positioning well, or choose not to and lose nothing. The best the monsters can do is position themselves to spread the damage around, not prevent it.

@ShadowRanger I think you are right if you only consider high AC tanks and if you use the rule that they only get hit when their AC gets hit. And that is one possible variant rule (and the one I quote, and that the 2014 rules had). But the question had not assumed this exact mechanic - it could just as well automatically hit the Tank if it misses the target by 1 or 2 points. Moreover, there are "Tank" characters that do not have super high AC, like Barbarians who just can soak the damage with resistance and large hp pools.

@NobodytheHobgoblin: Yes, but you described that specific approach to the ruling (it hits the cover if within two of hitting and high enough to hit the cover's AC) as an asymmetrical nerf to the players. It doesn't matter what the question assumed, I'm saying you described one specific way to handle it, then said it nerfed the players, when it doesn't. Sure, the Barbarian is an exception here where their AC isn't nuts (though being able to use shields helps) but traditional heavy armor+shield tanks benefit, and it's never worse for the players than for uniform AC monsters.
